# What does "157" represent in the line "primaryAddress is addr at storage 157"?

Tags: solidity

The above line is from a decompiled solidity smart contract.

```
def storage:
  stor0 is uint8 at storage 0
  stor0 is uint8 at storage 0 offset 8
  stor0 is uint256 at storage 0 offset 8
  balanceOf is mapping of uint256 at storage 51
  stor52 is mapping of uint256 at storage 52
  totalSupply is uint256 at storage 53
  name is array of uint256 at storage 104
  symbol is array of uint256 at storage 105
  decimals is uint8 at storage 106
  primaryAddress is addr at storage 157
```

Answer (score 0):

157 is the position of your value on storage.
For ex. you can read the contracts source with curl request below

```
curl --location --request POST 'localhost:8545/' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
"jsonrpc":"2.0", 
"method": "eth_getStorageAt", 
"params": [
    "CONTRACT_ADDRESS", 
    "POSITION",
    "latest"
], 
"id": 1
}'
```

I am assuming that 157 is the decimal so the hex value of 157 is 9D

and if you request "eth_getStorageAt" with position of 0x9D, then you will get the value of primaryAddress variable.

EDIT

I also forgot to mention that, each storage slots stores 32 bytes.